# Firestore: Creating Indexes for map values

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

How to create composite index for map values in a Document?

Data:

```
   {
      name: 'rodel',
      published: 
      {
          name: 'test'
      } 
   }
```

Do I need to create it like this?

```
  {
   "fieldPath": "published.name",
   "mode": "ASCENDING"
  }
```

Comment: Does that work the way you expect?

Comment: It's not working. I can't find examples in firebase docs either.

Comment: I see the problem is that the order of your queries matter, so the order in the indexes and the query should also match. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
  {
   "fieldPath": "published.`name`",
   "mode": "ASCENDING"
  }
`
```